# What is a periodic boundary condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Just encountered a PDE problem that said to use a periodic boundary condition on a time interval. No other information about the boundary conditions was given. Everything else looks like your typcial PDE (burgers), initial condition, domains. What is a periodic boundary condition?

Answer (score 0):

Periodic boundary conditions along time variable means that the solution repeats its behavior after a period $t_0$ that is something like $u(t)=u(t+t_0)$. What do you mean by infinite solution?